# I want to read the data from the Excel in selenium using java, but it is throwing the exception as ""main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError"

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to read the data from the Excel in selenium using java, but it is throwing the exception as below:

```
"main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerErrorat org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference.<init>(CellReference.java:110).
```

Tried multiple ways, but still getting the exception of main.
I have created the folder as "excel" in the selenium project, in which I have pasted the excel.

```
package utils;
    
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
    
    public class GetRowCount {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ReadExcel();
    }
    
        public static void ReadExcel() 
    {
    
            File src = new File("C:....");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
            
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook("fis");
        
            
            XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            
        
            String data0 =sheet1.getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
            
            System.out.println("Data from Excel is "+data0);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook("fis");
```

should be:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
```

Tested with file like [image: this example]

and modified class:

```
package utils;
    
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
    
public class GetRowCount {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ReadExcel();
    }
    
    public static void ReadExcel() throws IOException {
        File src = new File("C:\\test.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        String data0 = sheet1.getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println("Data from Excel is " + data0);
        // don't forget to close the workbook
        wb.close();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Data from Excel is FOO
```

PS: I'm using Apache POI 4.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Reading an excel sheet is basically called as utils, don't mixed reading data code, and your automation code
create utils class and use (property file reader)